# Hacer 'Click' a un boton HtmlControls desde el servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

En una pagina web 'aspx' utilizo componentes HtmlControls con la etiqueta runat="server".

```
<button type="button" id="MiBoton" runat="server">
```

Para hacer un 'Click' de un boton html desde el servidor actualmente utilizo esta forma con javascript:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "mensaje", "document.getElementById('MiBoton').click();", true);
```

¿ Hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo mas sencilla?

En CodeBehind no puedo hacer un:

```
MiBoton.Click()
```

Es decir no quiero pulsar el boton en el cliente para ejecutar codigo en el servidor sino al reves pulsar el boton desde el servidor para ejecutar codigo en el cliente

Answer (score 0):

Si usas `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` no estas realizando ninguna accion del lado del servidor, solo registras codigo `javascript` desde el `servidor` para que se ejecute en el `cliente (browser)`.

Si quieres ejecutar el codigo que pueda tener un boton tanto en el evento como en otra accion no necesitas simular un click, sino sacar ese codigo comun a otro metodo para ser reusado

```
public class WebAPage1 : Page {

   public void MiBoton_Click(...){
     CodigoComun();
   }

   public void OtraAccion(){
      CodigoComun();
   }

   private void CodigoComun(){
      //codigo
   }

}
```

de esta forma tanto desde el click del boton como desde otro sitio puede invocar la misma funcionalidad sin necesidad de simular ningun click, ni tener que ir hasta el cliente para luego volver con una llamada al servidor en el evento.

Comment: No es eso exactamente lo que quiero. En el lado del cliente tengo una ventana modal escrita en html5 con un boton que al pulsarlo esta ventana desaparece. Ese boton lo declaro como HtmlControl runat="server" para que sea reconocible desde el servidor en codebehind. Si llamo al codigo javascript desde el servidor para hacer un click del boton la ventana modal se cerrara ejecutando el codigo html5. Lo que quiero es hacer el click de ese boton HtmlControl referenciado como MiBoton desde el servidor para que haga el click en el lado del cliente y cierre la ventana modal.

Comment: Es decir no quiero pulsar el boton en el cliente para ejecutar codigo en el servidor sino al reves pulsar el boton desde el servidor para ejecutar codigo en el cliente.

Comment: Entonces lo que estas haciendo es correcto, la unica forma de realizar una accion en el cliente desde el servidor es usando javascript. Igualmente creo que estas mezclando un poco todos los conceptos, javascript para acciones del lado cliente y c# para el lado servidor y no se mezclan, bueno salvo que te interesa pasar a Blazor, pero eso ya seria WebAssembly y es otro tema

Comment: Sino otra alternativa implicaria empezar a usar llamadas jquery con $.ajax o si quieres enviar una accion desde el servidor al cliente usar SignalR

Comment: Tengo que hacerlo asi porque estoy mostrando en la pagina del lado del cliente con bootstrap, javascript, html5. En el lado del servidor lo uso para conectarme a base de datos y pasar esa informacion luego al cliente. No uso MVC sino Codebehind.

Comment: Es indistinto que sea o no mvc, los conceptos no cambian. Si quieres enviar info desde el cliente al servidor sin post de la pagina usa jquery. Si quieres enviar datos desde el servidor al cliente sin un request usa SignalR.

Comment: Para enviar datos del cliente al servidor uso Scriptmanager y updatepanel que hace lo mismo que jquery. En realidad no es que necesite en este caso enviar datos del servidor al cliente sino que tengo que lanzar un evento del servidor al cliente y ese evento es un click() al boton del cliente. Para usar SignalR quizas sea complicar demasiado para usarlo solo para hacer click()